# Google Visualization Table API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

So I have made a google visualization table that shows the store name , sales and speed of service info. 
            I have made two tables mystore ( the first table) and allStores(the second table). So the myStore is the owners store info and
            the allStore is the genral info of that franchise.
            So  when you click on the sales header on the allStore table it will order from the highest or lowest and What i want to do is to reflect that on the 
            owners store's rank in the myStore table, so eg: If greerton is one of the owners store and the if the sales info is ranked third for it 
            it should show that up in myStore. I have tried to find related info but they were all using html table. 
Please Help =)

```
   <div id="table_div2"></div>
   <div id="table_div4"></div>
```

google.setOnLoadCallback(myStore);
         google.setOnLoadCallback(allStores);

```
    function myStore() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Store Name');
        data.addColumn('number', ' Sales');
        data.addColumn('number','SOS');
         data.addRows([
          ['Bayfair',{ v: 4895, f: '$4895' },{v: 68, f: '$68'}],
          ['Greerton',{ v: 3158, f: '$3158' },{v: 126, f: '$126'}]

        ]);

        var Table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div2'));

        Table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });
        }

        function allStores() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Store Name');
        data.addColumn('number', ' Sales');
        data.addColumn('number','SOS');
         data.addRows([
          ['Bayfair',{ v: 4895, f: '$4895' },{v: 68, f: '68'}],
          ['Greerton',{ v: 3158, f: '$3158' },{v: 126, f: '126'}],
          ['Frankton',{ v: 3689, f: '$3689' },{v: 79, f: '79'}],

          ['Mt Manganui',{ v: 3069, f: '$3069' },{v: 72, f: '72'}],
          ['Tauranga',{ v: 2689, f: '$2689' },{v: 68, f: '68'}],
          ['Te Rapa',{ v: 2269, f: '$2269' },{v: 143, f: '143'}],
          ['The Base',{ v: 1895, f: '$1895' },{v: 125, f: '125'}],

        ]);

        var Table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div4'));

        Table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });

        }
        var stores= ["Bayfair","Greerton"];
        function Take (){


        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1gm96gqy/

Comment: More clarification is needed, perhaps a sketch of what you want in the other table ... "What i want to do is to reflect that on the owners store's rank in the myStore table, so eg: If greerton is one of the owners store and the if the sales info is ranked third for it it should show that up in myStore." You say ... "Reflect that" -- how? Add a column, a note, color it? Again "it it should show that up" what is "that" ? How?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's something to get you started. See:

https://jsfiddle.net/1gm96gqy/4/

Added is a function that highlights stores in the second list if they appear in the first list. It uses jQuery. It is tied to both the initial draw event and any time the data is sorted.

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(myStore);
  google.setOnLoadCallback(allStores);
  function highlightStores(){
        // make a list of all the stores in the first table
        var storerows = $('#table_div2').find('tr');
        // make a list of all the stores in second table
        var allstorerows = $('#table_div4').find('tr');
        allstorerows.each(function(i,hstore){
          var thestore = $(hstore).children()[1];
          var hstorename = $($(hstore).children()[1]).text();
          storerows.each(function(j,store){
             if(store.children[1].nodeName != 'TH'){
             var storename = $($(store).children()[1]).text();
             if (storename == hstorename){
               $(hstore).attr('style','background-color:yellow');
             }
             }
          })

          })
  }

          function myStore() {
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

              data.addColumn('string', 'Store Name');
              data.addColumn('number', ' Sales');
              data.addColumn('number','SOS');
               data.addRows([
                ['Bayfair',{ v: 4895, f: '$4895' },{v: 68, f: '$68'}],
                ['Greerton',{ v: 3158, f: '$3158' },{v: 126, f: '$126'}]

              ]);

              var Table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div2'));

              Table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });
              }

              function allStores() {
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

              data.addColumn('string', 'Store Name');
              data.addColumn('number', ' Sales');
              data.addColumn('number','SOS');
               data.addRows([
                ['Bayfair',{ v: 4895, f: '$4895' },{v: 68, f: '68'}],
                ['Greerton',{ v: 3158, f: '$3158' },{v: 126, f: '126'}],
                ['Frankton',{ v: 3689, f: '$3689' },{v: 79, f: '79'}],

                ['Mt Manganui',{ v: 3069, f: '$3069' },{v: 72, f: '72'}],
                ['Tauranga',{ v: 2689, f: '$2689' },{v: 68, f: '68'}],
                ['Te Rapa',{ v: 2269, f: '$2269' },{v: 143, f: '143'}],
                ['The Base',{ v: 1895, f: '$1895' },{v: 125, f: '125'}],

              ]);

              var Table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div4'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(Table, 'ready', highlightStores);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(Table, 'sort', highlightStores);
              Table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });


              }
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: The answer was helpful, though after a lot of editing i still didn't seem to figure it out, So in my new code , i want my bottom table  to literally move to the same position as the information in the top table when you press the sales header or the SOS header. So for example When I click sales Greerton is ranked 5th, I want number 5 to show up in  my rank column  in the bottom table     https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: Ignore the above jsfiddle above this is actual edited version > https://jsfiddle.net/k2o9fLzo/

Comment: Let me edit you comment -- I believe what you want is "no matter what the sorting is, I want the column headed 'rank' in the first table to show the value of the second table" ... if you click sales, the second table would have 5, Greerton ... 1.The Base. If you click SOS, the second table woyuld have 6, Greerton ... 5, The Base ? Correct?

Comment: That comment  based on your new fiddle where the tables are reversed.

Comment: I got it working now, though I am trying to get a up-down arrow on the second (main) table, when you click on sales or SOS, another table pops up where if you click on one of the headers on that table an arrow director pops up, i want that to happen on the main table as currently it doesn't do that  =)